# Custom shape in flutter ( with curved edges )

Tags: flutter, user-interface, stack

Hello am trying to achieve this UI in flutter

**Expected output**

[image]

**Output what am getting now**

[image]

> How to make that curve before LTE and ZTL.
> How to position widgets in flutter when using stack other than the positioned widget?

The code for what I have done so far.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.023,
        ),
        Stack(children: [
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), //color of shadow
                      spreadRadius: 2, //spread radius
                      blurRadius: 3, // blur radius
                      offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                    ),
                  ],
                  color: const Color(0xff0C2242),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17))),
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17))),
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(17))),
            ),
          )
        ])
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check `ShapeBorder` official documentation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the original UI will be achieved. So, here is the suggestion
below the graph create a Row widget and add three widgets of card
then try changing the border shape based on your shape

Comment: ok i will try that

Answer (score 0):

you should use CustomClipper .
read the documentation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html